# Free SSH and FTP client in-one?

Tags: gratis, windows-7, ssh, portable, sftp

Is there a free, lightweight SSH and FTP client in-one?

I would like:

- SSH console support
- it to be free
- (S)FTP (**with** GUI) support
- lightweight
- portable
- it to run on Windows 7

Basically, I'm looking for WinSCP and PuTTY in one program, that's free, lightweight and portable.

Comment: Check out Cyberduck.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Thanks - but does Cyberduck have SSH support? It seems it only has FTP and SFTP support...

Comment: You mean SSH console ? I'm afraid it can't do that.

Comment: Yep, I mean SSH console. Thanks for the suggestion anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Bitvise SSH Client](http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client) *(formerly Tunnelier)*

- [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), [for personal use](http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-license)
- Has an SSH console
- Supports (S)FTP, with GUI
- [Installer is `10.80 MB`](http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download), IMHO quite small for the features it offers
- [Portable version available](http://tp.vbap.com.au/download) (made by a third party - also, it isn't up-to-date with the official version*) which is `7.04 MB` zip'ed
- Works on Windows 2000 up to and including Windows 8.1 (32-bit and 64-bit)
- Screenshots are available here: [Screenshots](http://www.bitvise.com/screenshots)

**at the time of writing, the official version is 6.22 <sup>(31/01/2015)</sup> and the portable version is 6.04 <sup>(04/08/2014)</sup>*